# Movie about space pirates that involved putting lots of ball bombs in a space diplomat

Tags: story-identification, movie, space, pirates

I watched it on cable and it was all I can remember. The bad pirate had an eye-patch. Really nice and friendly? I hope someone can remember and point to such a movie. It was emulating *Escape from L.A.*, in a space frontier setting in a way.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this movie, and when do you think it might've been made? Also, in which country and language did you watch this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pretty sure this is ***[Space Marines](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117706/)*** (1996).

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/SpaceMarines):

> Not the Warhammer 40,000 CGI film but a 1996 action film that concerns itself with a bunch of Space Marines trying to recover a hostage from **a gang of Space Pirates (complete with eyepatches), called the Infinity Brigade, led by John Pyper-Ferguson as Colonel Fraser. It doesn't go well. When kidnapping their hostage it turns out the pirates had also acquired a large amount of utrinium/antimatter, which Col. Fraser soon uses to make tiny, swallowable bombs.**
>
> **After Col. Fraser blows up the hostage during the exchange he takes the ambassador, his aide and a disguised marine hostage instead, planning to use the ambassador as a human bomb to force the local galactic federation to give him tons of gold.** And so the captured marine spends his time trying to escape from and/or defeat the Colonel while convincing the aide to stop being a bitch and start helping. The rest of the marines mount a rescue while struggling against the bureaucracy of the galactic security council and Pyper-Ferguson hams it up all around the set.

The lead villain -- pictured on the left in the image below -- is Colonel Fraser; a former marine turned space pirate, with a cybernetic leg and a rather theatrical speaking style. The man wearing the eyepatch is his second-in-command, Gunther; a man of few words.

In his gloved right hand, Fraser is shown holding a small metal sphere, which is one of a number of bombs the pirates made from a shipment of 'utrinium' they stole from a space freighter near the start of the movie.

The pirates surgically implant a kilogram of these bombs into the stomach of Ambassador Nakamura (played by [James Shigeta](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0793363/)), and threaten to blow him up in a room full of United Planets Security Council members, if they aren't given a hundred kilos of gold.

[image]

Comment: 100kg gold?  What, there's been a [massive _deflation_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTmXHvGZiSY)?

Comment: Exactly, man! They implanted bombs in the stomach of the ambassador! Lovely space opera movie!

Comment: And yes: the lead villain looked exactly like a Space Knave of the cards. Moustaches and behaviour. I loved that movie. Do you remember "Crossworlds" with late Rutger Hauer, lovely Andrea Roth and Josh Charles?

Comment: @Chavdar Likov - I've seen bits of _Crossworlds_, but I don't think I've watched it from start to finish, or at least I don't remember the full story too well. I can tell you that the lead villain from _Space Marines_ also played a villain in a martial arts/action film called _Drive (1997)_, starring Mark Dacascos. It has excellent fight scenes, and is well worth checking out, if you like that sort of thing and haven't seen it already.